# Googlesheets script: mailApp sending multiple emails to specified cc email

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to send an email with inline images to a series of users with myself in cc (myself@hotmail.com). I am trying to do this with the code written bellow. Everything seemed to work, but as soon as I added cc: 'myself@hotmail.com' it broke. My email gets send to the recipient 1x, but also to 'myself@hotmail.com' 8x. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, any help is much appreciated.

```
function sendEmails() {
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails").activate(); //makes sure your google sheets has the correct sheet open where you specify the emails and names
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); //defines spreadsheet to use
  var lr = ss.getLastRow(); //gets last row on which there is data
  
  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Template').getRange(1, 1).getValue() //gets email body from sheet 'template' which is defined in cell 1,1 -- make sure your sheet has same name else it won't work
  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();  //gets number of emails that you can still send
 

  // Image URLs
  var img1Url = "https://i.imgur.com/PRIVATE.png"; //CHANGE PRIVATE TAG
  var img2Url = "https://i.imgur.com/PRIVATE.png"; //CHANGE PRIVATE TAG

  // Fetch images as blobs, set names for attachments
  var img1Blob = UrlFetchApp
                            .fetch(img1Url)
                            .getBlob()
                            .setName("img1Blob");   
  var img2Blob = UrlFetchApp
                            .fetch(img2Url)
                            .getBlob()
                            .setName("img2Blob");

  //embeded image tags for email
  var bodyImg1 = "<img src='cid:img1' style='width:1000px; height:1500px;'/>"; //specify img size here
  var bodyImg2 = "<img src='cid:img2' style='width:1000px; height:1500px;'/>"; //specify img size here
    
 
  if((lr-1) > quotaLeft){
    Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " left and you're trying to send " + (lr-1) + " emails. Emails were not send"); //gives standard warning message if number of emails to be send exceeds limit
  } else {
    
      for (var i = 2; i<=lr;i++){  
      
         var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue(); //gets email in excel sheet
         var currentName = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue(); //gets name in excel sheet
      
         var subjectLine = "Invitation"; //title of email
         var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}", currentName); //replaces name in template with name of current cell, see templateText var
      
         MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, subjectLine, {htmlBody: messageBody + bodyImg1 + bodyImg2, inlineImages:{img1: img1Blob,img2: img2Blob}, cc: 'myself@hotmail.com'});
      
    } //close for loop
  } //close else statement
} //close function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

MailApp.sendEmail({ to: currentEmail, subject: subjectLine, cc: 'myself@hotmail.com', htmlBody: messageBody + bodyImg1 + bodyImg2, inlineImages:{img1: img1Blob,img2: img2Blob}});